# Python SQLAlchemy: TypeError: connect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've tried to run the code below multiple times, but continue getting the error :

```
TypeError: connect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

I already tried changing the `username` field to user within the `createEngine` function. Was looking to see if anyone could help me figure this out :

```
db_user = os.environ.get("filleruser")
db_pass = os.environ.get("fillerpw")
db_name = os.environ.get("fillerdatabasename")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ.get("fillerconnectionname")

app = Flask(__name__)

logger = logging.getLogger()

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='postgres+pg8000',
        username=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name,
        query={
            'unix_sock': '/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432'.format(
                cloud_sql_connection_name)
        }
    ),
    max_overflow=2,
    pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
    pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    users = []
    with db.connect() as conn:
        # Execute the query and fetch all results
        recent_votes = conn.execute(
            "SELECT name FROM test"
        ).fetchall()
        # Convert the results into a list of dicts representing votes
        for row in recent_votes:
            votes.append({
                'name': row[0],
            })
            print(row)

    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        names=users
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check if the variable `db_user` is populated?

Comment: Great point! I ran print(db_user) in main and it came out as 'None'. How would I go about populating it correctly?

Comment: That would mean that your OS environment variable is empty. If you are on linux, you can check if it's set with `printenv`

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you

Comment: You can set the environment variable in your terminal shell with `export filleruser=PASSWORD`